# pandas pivot table value as column or index

Tags: pandas

How can I use the same column as used in 'values' for 'column' or 'index'?

For example:

```
pd.pivot_table(data, values='Survived', index=['Survived', 'Sex', 'Pclass'],
               aggfunc=len, margins=True)
```

values and index use the same column Survived. When I try to run the above I get

```
ValueError: Grouper for 'Survived' not 1-dimensional
```

However, if instead of values='Survived' I use another column, the pivot_table works fine.

Comment: I think you have to create new column with different name, but with same values - `data['Survived1'] = data['Survived']` and then use `df = pd.pivot_table(data, values='Survived', index=['Survived1', 'Sex', 'Pclass'],
               aggfunc=len, margins=True)`

Comment: I'm hoping to avoid it, although it's the pragmatic solution

Comment: Hmmm, I think it is unusually way of using `pivot_table`, so it doesnt work.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you're trying to achieve here can be better implemented using [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)

Answer (score 4):

One issue I'm seeing is that you haven't set the `columns` argument when calling `pivot_table` (which tells pandas what values to use as the column headers for the `pivot_table` output).

A pivot table operation is actually a succession of `groupby -> aggregate -> unstack`. Say you have this `DataFrame`:

```
    survived sex pclass  other
0      False   f      a     29
1       True   f      b      6
2       True   f      b     22
3      False   m      b     55
4      False   f      a     59
..       ...  ..    ...    ...
95     False   f      a     66
96     False   f      c     42
97      True   m      c     93
98      True   m      c     59
99     False   f      b     93
```

You can pivot this table using `pivot_table`:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='sex', columns='pclass', values='other', aggfunc=sum)
```

```
pclass     a    b     c
sex                    
f       1000  840   306
m        728  851  1247
```

Or you can get the same result using `groupby` and `unstack`:

```
df.groupby(['sex', 'pclass'])['other'].sum().unstack()
```

```
pclass     a    b     c
sex                    
f       1000  840   306
m        728  851  1247
```

The point of this short story is that pivot tables are actually `groupby` operations. In your case, you're trying to group by `['Survived', 'Sex', 'Pclass']` and aggregate `'Survived'` again using `len`. That doesn't make much sense since `'Survived'` is already part of output table index (which is why `pivot_table` gives you an error).

You can, if you really want to make this work, use `groupby` instead:

```
df.groupby(['survived', 'sex', 'pclass', 'other']['survived'].apply(len).unstack()
```

However, I think you actually want to achieve something else, not sure what though.